# How can I do mapreduce on multiple columns in dataframe in scala?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, mapreduce

My spark dataframe looks like this:

```
+-------+------+-------+------+------+
|userid1|time  |userid2|name1 |name2 |
+-------+------+-------+------+------+
|23     |1     |33     |user1 |user2 | 
|23     |2     |33     |new   |user2 |
|231    |1     |23     |231n  |new   |
|231    |4     |33     |231n  |user2 |
+-------+------+-------+------+------+
```

For each row, there are 2 userids, with corresponding names, but only one time.

I want to get the latest name for each user. it's like combining the colomn `userid1` and `userid2`.

The result should be:

```
+------+-----------+
|userid|latest name|
+------+-----------+
|23    |new        |
|33    |user2      |
|231   |231n       |
+------+-----------+
```

How can I do this?

I am thinking of using `partitonBy` but I don't know how to combine the result of column `userid1` and `userid2` and get the latest name.

I am also thinking about using `rdd.flatMap((row => row._1 -> row._2),(row => row._3 -> row._2)).reduceByKey(_ max _))`
but it's dataframe, not rdd, and I'm not sure about the syntax. The col and $ in daatframe really confuse me.(sorry I'm relatively new to Spark.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this solution?

```
import spark.implicits._

val users = Seq(
  (23, 1, 33, "user1", "user2"),
  (23, 2, 33, "new", "user2"),
  (231, 1, 23, "231", "new"),
  (231, 4, 33, "231", "user2")
).toDF("userid1", "time", "userid2", "name1", "name2")

val users1 = users.select(col("userid1").as("userid"), col("name1").as("name"), col("time"))
val users2 = users.select(col("userid2").as("userid"), col("name2").as("name"), col("time"))

val unitedUsers = users1.union(users2)

val resultDf = unitedUsers
  .withColumn("max_time", max("time").over(Window.partitionBy("userid")))
  .where(col("max_time") === col("time"))
  .select(col("userid"), col("name").as("latest_name"))
  .distinct()
```

Comment: i woud encounter this error ```<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
  .withColumn("max_time", max("time").over(Window.partitionBy("userid")))
  ^``` it seems like I cannot use withColumn.

Comment: Are you trying to run from spark shell?

Comment: i am trying to run from Zeppline Notebook with spark interpreter.

Comment: Probably you should put whole command in one line in zeppelin. I mean Val resultDf = ...